# Recursively generate an object from a string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string, object, recursion

In my efforts in transmuting a string to an object i wanted to push myself to into generating a JSON like structure but with minimal syntax
based on indentation (like jade) instead of curly braces & quotes.

I have got close to what i needed but i cant figure out how to generate an object with the data produced.

I know i have to use `recursion` to to dynamically create the object based on the `indentation` of each line or at least thats what im thinking.

I would include the code logic here but its more readable in a text editor.
Here is the [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oLwXra?editors=0110).

**input**

```js
project = MyApp
  files
    js = [one.js , two.js ,three.js ,coffe ,382, 90]
    scss = [pannel.scss , house.scss]
  compiled
    files = [main.js , main.css , main.html]
    opts = (type : es2015 , msg : multi line string ,online : true , isArray : probably )
  src = ./src
  dest = ./dest
  tree
    level1
      level2
        level3
          out = ./out/to/path
```

**output**

```js
{
  project:'MyApp',
    files:{
      js:['one.js' ,' two.js' ,'three.js'],
      scss:['pannel.scss' , 'house.scss']
    },
  compiled:{
    files:['main.js' ,'main.css','main.html'],
    opt:{type:'es2015',msg:'multi line string' , online:'true' ,isArray:'probably'}
  },
  src:'./src',
  dest:'./dest',
  tree:{
    level1:{
      level2:{
        level3:{
          out:'./output/to/path'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I cannot find your best attempt in your code on solving your own issue. Have any?

Comment: thats just it... i am stumped at creating the recursion process. i dont know to create the nested properties with the data that the code produces

Comment: Seems like a nice question and a fun JS mini project, but you should really show the minimal effort in trying something and sharing it with us!

Comment: "*I would include the code logic here but its more readable in a text editor*" - no. Everybody knows how to copy code into his favourite editor. Put the code in the question, not at some arbitrary code sharehoster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your values is a kind of relaxed `JSON`. After looking on the web I found a library that does pretty mutch what you want (in parsing values), the only difference is that the `key/value` delimiter is `=`. So, I changed the code to meet your requirements with some limitations see [1]. Concerning the tree building, I've written my own version. Please check the snippet:

```js
let input = `
project = MyApp
  files
    js = [one.js , two.js ,three.js ,coffe ,382, 90]
    scss = [pannel.scss , house.scss]
  compiled
    files = [main.js , main.css , main.html]
    opts = (type : es2015 , msg : "mult ilin estring" ,online : true , isArray : probably )
  src = ./src
  dest = ./dest
  tree
    level1
      level2
        level3
          out = ./out/to/path
`
let result = {};
let lines = input.split('\n').slice(1, -1);//Get lines and remove start/end space.
let cursor = result;//Keep track of current position
let path = []; //Store old psition to make it easy reach upper levels.
path.push(result);
let currentLevel = 0;

for(var i in lines) {

  let level = lines[i].search(/\S/);
  let line = lines[i].substr(level);
  
  if(level < currentLevel) {
     path.pop();
  }
  cursor = path[path.length-1];
  currentLevel = level;
  
  if(line.indexOf('=') === -1) {
    cursor[line] = {};
    path.push(cursor[line]);
    cursor = cursor[line];
  } else {
    var parts = line.split(/\s*=\s*/);
    //Here I used the modified jsonlite
    cursor[parts[0]] = jsonlite.parse(parts[1], false);
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/iRbouh/6d2889a55794b03bb88bf15149a931d1/raw/53728a446051af8752ea15d83e27217e141a9b74/jsonlite.js"></script>
```

[1] : Object key, string value, number value, true, false, null in values can all be without quotes, as long as they don't contain special characters: spaces( , `\t`, `\n`...), double quote(`"`), comma(`,`), square brackets(`[,]`), object start and end (`{`, `}` or `(`, `)`, depending on options), pair separators (`:`).